SQL Server Memory-Optimized tables: timestamp columns
I am researching how to convert some physical tables to memory-optimized tables.
But these tables have timestamp column.
This data type is not supported in MO. How to replace it? Now these columns used in app to compare and check if another app changed the row.

You can use a datetime stamp which you can compare against instead when checking for concurrent changes, of course this requires all places to update it, but it's possible to use trigger for that in worst case. On the other hand, i'm a bit wary when people randomly convert tables to memory tables, what's your use case?

I am researching ways to optimize performance, now I think to convert some of tables to MO. At least I can use MP instead of temp tables and table variables.

@siggemannen the datetime has lass precise in comparison with ts, i.e. now I have N records with the same datetime values but different ts

You can use datetime2 perhaps, but yeah, if you have that much activity going on, then perhaps you have bigger problems than timestamps

Is performance a problem? I'd say memory optimized table wasn't a magic bullet on solving anything back when i tested it

I just want to jump in here in that I strongly believe that timestamp as used here, is the deprecated (and unfortunately named) synonym for rowversion. If so, ongoing discussion on the merits of datetime et al are largely irrelevant.

I am not quite sure why you would want rowversion in a MO table. Have you run the Memory Optimization Advisor?
You could try using a trigger to update a column with a sequence or NEWID().

Because the timestamp columns already are in tables and used in apps.  Advisor said me ts is not supported

Then why do you want to make this a MO table? Are you sure of the use case?

I am searching ways to improve performance of our database. It works on SQL 2022, has not so large size but bad performance on  some queries
